# Implementing Biber for Biblatex in Microsoft Visual Studio Code

Tags: biblatex, biber

it is my first question here, so please be gentle, I try to explain the problem as good as I can. I don't have any programming background, only using LaTeX for Thesis writing in chemsitry.

I'm unsing VS Code as an editor with the LaTeX Workshop Extension by James Yu and TEXlive. The tool pdflatex and bibtex already exsists also the project for pdflatex-->bibtex-->pdflatex-->pdflatex

But now i want to include biber for the biblatex package. 
Is there a way to include it and how do i do it? i guess there is command for biber to implement it as a tool and then i can create a new project like pdflatex-->biber--> etc.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! According to https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=James-Yu.latex-workshop the *LaTeX Workshop Extension* can run `latexmk`. That tool will automatically run LaTeX and Biber as required, so that might be an option (if you have Perl installed, that is).

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/455648/35864 might be interesting.

Comment: Perfect, the link you gave was how i thought it might work. I also switched pdflatex to xelatex (that was why latexmk was not the preferd option). Their was still in error with the uniquename-option but that was already solved in another thread.

Answer (score 20):

The solution is quit simple, just as is described in the link for luatex.
[LuaLaTeX not recognised as a VS Code tool](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/455648/35864)

So to implement it, you open the settings and go into `settings.json` and add the tools xelatex and biber and then make a recipe out of it.

```
"latex-workshop.latex.tools": [
    {
        "name": "xelatex",
        "command": "xelatex",
        "args": [
            "-synctex=1",
            "-interaction=nonstopmode",
            "-file-line-error",
            "%DOC%"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "biber",
        "command": "biber",
        "args": [
            "%DOCFILE%"
        ]
    }
],
"latex-workshop.latex.recipes": [
    {
        "name": "xelatex -> biber -> xelatex*2",
        "tools": [
            "xelatex",
            "biber",
            "xelatex",
            "xelatex"
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Thank you so much!