# Biblatex and biber in VS Code

Tags: biblatex, visual-studio-code

I've just changed from TexMaker to VS Code and have since been unable to compile .tex documents that use .bib bibliographies and biblatex with biber. I have also tried bibtex, but it doesn't work either. I have latexmk installed and latex-workshop, I all I have read about it says that bibtex should work fine with the compilation process just by saving, but it does not. I have also read that to use biblatex I should create a new recipe, but I don't know how to do this. I have searched here and other questions couldn't help me, so I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/459933/134144 might be interesting.

Comment: I have seen this, but he uses xelatex. Can I just change it to pdflatex?

Comment: Yes you can, it should work out of the box

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864. But if VS code runs `latexmk` for you everything should work fine.

Comment: I'm not sure what document I have to edit. Is it setting.json?

Comment: I don't know either, but the answer for VS code in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 appears to have a step-by-step instruction with pictures that should lead you there.

Comment: I have just followed it, but there is no {} as step 1.2 mentions, so I added the text from the following steps to settings.json and it doesn't work...

Comment: I have done what is in tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864, but substituting 'pdflatex' in place of 'xelatex'. The build doesn't work and says "pdflatex not defined".