# Cannot select lualatex or xelatex with magic comment in vscode with latex workshop

Tags: xetex, luatex, vscode, latex-workshop

The magic comment `% !TEX program = lualatex` no longer works when using VSCode with latex workshop. I found that Latex Workshop no longer supports magic comments  by default for  [security reasons](https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/issues/3027).

What is a minimal workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for a workaround. Just uncheck the `latex-workshop.latex.build.forceRecipeUsage` option.

Comment: Took hours to realize this! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I found that a subset of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/455648/lualatex-not-recognised-as-a-vs-code-tool) was sufficient to get it working. I added the following to my project `.vscode/settings.json`

```
{
    "latex-workshop.latex.recipe.default": "latexmk (lualatex)",
    "latex-workshop.latex.tools": [
        {
            "name": "lualatexmk",
            "command": "latexmk",
            "args": [
                "-lualatex",
            ]
        }
    ],
    "latex-workshop.latex.recipes": [
        {
            "name": "latexmk (lualatex)",
            "tools": [
                "lualatexmk"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```