# LuaLatex in VSCode - Recipe terminated with fatal error: spawn latexmk ENOENT

Tags: lua, vscode, latex-workshop

I am using VSCode with LaTeX Workshop installed, and TexLive as engine. I can use pdflatex just fine, however if I want to use any other recipe I get this error.

Naturally, I have TexLive added to PATH (C:\texlive\2023\bin\windows).

My settings.json:

```
{
"workbench.editorAssociations": {
    "*.pdf": "latex-workshop-pdf-hook"
},
"latex-workshop.bibtex-fields.sort.enabled": true,
"latex-workshop.intellisense.citation.backend": "biblatex",
"latex-workshop.latex.recipes": [

    {
        "name": "standard",
        "tools": [
            "pdflatex",
            "biber",
            "pdflatex",
            "pdflatex"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "biber",
        "tools": [
            "biber"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "latexmk",
        "tools": [
            "latexmk"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "latexmk (latexmkrc)",
        "tools": [
            "latexmk_rconly"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "latexmk (lualatex)",
        "tools": [
            "lualatexmk"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "latexmk (xelatex)",
        "tools": [
            "xelatexmk"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "pdflatex -> bibtex -> pdflatex * 2",
        "tools": [
            "pdflatex",
            "biblatex",
            "pdflatex",
            "pdflatex"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Compile Rnw files",
        "tools": [
            "rnw2tex",
            "latexmk"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Compile Jnw files",
        "tools": [
            "jnw2tex",
            "latexmk"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Compile Pnw files",
        "tools": [
            "pnw2tex",
            "latexmk"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "tectonic",
        "tools": [
            "tectonic"
        ]
    }
],
"latex-workshop.latex.tools": [

    {
        "name": "latexmk",
        "command": "latexmk",
        "args": [
            "-synctex=1",
            "-interaction=nonstopmode",
            "-file-line-error",
            "-pdf",
            "-outdir=%OUTDIR%",
            "%DOC%"
        ],
        "env": {}
    },
    {
        "name": "xelatex",
        "command": "xelatex",
        "args": [
            "-synctex=1",
            "-interaction=nonstopmode",
            "-file-line-error",
            "%DOC%"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "biber",
        "command": "biber",
        "args": [
            "%DOCFILE%"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "lualatexmk",
        "command": "latexmk",
        "args": [
            "-synctex=1",
            "-interaction=nonstopmode",
            "-file-line-error",
            "-lualatex",
            "-outdir=%OUTDIR%",
            "%DOC%"
        ],
        "env": {}
    },
    {
        "name": "xelatexmk",
        "command": "latexmk",
        "args": [
            "-synctex=1",
            "-interaction=nonstopmode",
            "-file-line-error",
            "-xelatex",
            "-outdir=%OUTDIR%",
            "%DOC%"
        ],
        "env": {}
    },
    {
        "name": "latexmk_rconly",
        "command": "latexmk",
        "args": [
            "%DOC%"
        ],
        "env": {}
    },
    {
        "name": "pdflatex",
        "command": "pdflatex",
        "args": [
            "-synctex=1",
            "-interaction=nonstopmode",
            "-file-line-error",
            "%DOC%"
        ],
        "env": {}
    },
    {
        "name": "rnw2tex",
        "command": "Rscript",
        "args": [
            "-e",
            "knitr::opts_knit$set(concordance = TRUE); knitr::knit('%DOCFILE_EXT%')"
        ],
        "env": {}
    },
    {
        "name": "jnw2tex",
        "command": "julia",
        "args": [
            "-e",
            "using Weave; weave(\"%DOC_EXT%\", doctype=\"tex\")"
        ],
        "env": {}
    },
    {
        "name": "jnw2texminted",
        "command": "julia",
        "args": [
            "-e",
            "using Weave; weave(\"%DOC_EXT%\", doctype=\"texminted\")"
        ],
        "env": {}
    },
    {
        "name": "pnw2tex",
        "command": "pweave",
        "args": [
            "-f",
            "tex",
            "%DOC_EXT%"
        ],
        "env": {}
    },
    {
        "name": "pnw2texminted",
        "command": "pweave",
        "args": [
            "-f",
            "texminted",
            "%DOC_EXT%"
        ],
        "env": {}
    },
    {
        "name": "tectonic",
        "command": "tectonic",
        "args": [
            "--synctex",
            "--keep-logs",
            "%DOC%.tex"
        ],
        "env": {}
    }
],
"git.confirmSync": false,
"git.autofetch": true,
"git.enableSmartCommit": true,
"ltex.completionEnabled": true,
"ltex.latex.commands": {
    "keywords": "default"
},
"ltex.language" : "en-GB",
"editor.inlineSuggest.suppressSuggestions": true,
"ltex.additionalRules.languageModel": "en-GB",
"latex-utilities.countWord.format": "${wordsBody} Words"
```

}

No other recipe works, just the pdflatex one, so I'm probably doing something wrong with the config somewhere, but I don't know what.

EDIT:
LuaLaTeX is available, since i got the following output in the terminal by running `lualatex --version`

```
    This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.17.0 (TeX Live 2023)
Development id: 7581

Execute  'luahbtex --credits'  for credits and version details.

There is NO warranty. Redistribution of this software is covered by
the terms of the GNU General Public License, version 2 or (at your option)
any later version. For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the LuaTeX source.

LuaTeX is Copyright 2022 Taco Hoekwater and the LuaTeX Team.
```

Comment: there is no tool "biblatex", biblatex is a latex package, I also don't have lualatexmk or xelatexmk.

Comment: yeah i guess so, but even then those work. It's the lualatexmk that doesn't work Thanks for pointing that one out, vscode was just skipping it when running, but I haven't used anything else besides the standard anyway. It is a while since I set things up.

Comment: found the solution here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/455648/lualatex-not-recognised-as-a-vs-code-tool, will mark this as duplicate